# How do I create a filter that will return the desired card from the JSONArray array?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs3, filtering

I don't understand how to create a filter that will return the desired card from an array if the buttons are also an array JSON array. By clicking on the button with the value attached to it, find a matching value in another array and return this card

```
//brand.json  [
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Brand 1",
  "sort": "100",
  "code": "brand_1"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Brand 2",
  "sort": "200",
  "code": "brand_2"
}
//items.Json
 [
{
  "type": "simple",
  "id": 1,
  "sku": "s1",
  "title": "Product 1",
  "regular_price": {
    "currency": "USD",
    "value": 27.12
  },
  "image": "/images/1.png",
  "brand": 9
  },
  Code: 
    <div class="nav">
        <span class="w-full my-4 "> All brands</span>
        <hr />
        <div class="btn" v-for="(item, id) in brand" :key="id" @click="filter">{{ item.title 
     }}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3" v-for="(item, id) in items" :key="id">
            <img src="./logo.png" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
            <br> {{ item.title }} <br> brand {{ item.brand }} <br> ${{ 
           item.regular_price.value }}
            <div class="btn me-md-2" id="btn"    @click="$emit('addToCart', value)"> Add to 
           cart</div>
           </div>
        </div>
         </div>
    <script>
      import brand from '@/components/brand.json';
  import items from '@/components/items.json';
  export default {
    name: "App",
    data: () => ({
    brand,
    items,
    filteredBrand: [],
}),
} </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly try like following snippet, with computed property and method:

```js
const brand = [{"id": 1, "title": "Brand 1", "sort": "100", "code": "brand_1"}, {"id": 2, "title": "Brand 2", "sort": "200", "code": "brand_2"}]
const items = [{"type": "simple", "id": 1, "sku": "s1", "title": "Product 1", "regular_price": {"currency": "USD", "value": 27.12}, "image": "/images/1.png", "brand": 1}, {"type": "simple", "id": 2, "sku": "s1", "title": "Product 2", "regular_price": {"currency": "USD", "value": 37.88}, "image": "/images/1.png", "brand": 2}, {"type": "simple", "id": 3, "sku": "s1", "title": "Product 3", "regular_price": {"currency": "USD", "value": 39.77}, "image": "/images/1.png", "brand": 2}]
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data: () => ({
    brand,
    items,
    filteredBrand: null,
  }),
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      return this.filteredBrand ? this.items.filter(i => i.brand === this.filteredBrand) : this.items
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterByBrand(brand = null) {
      this.filteredBrand = brand
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="nav">
    <span class="btn btn-primary" @click="filterByBrand()"> All brands</span>
    <div class="btn btn-secondary" v-for="(item, id) in brand" :key="id" @click="filterByBrand(item.id)">{{ item.title }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" v-for="(item, id) in filteredItems" :key="id">
        <br> {{ item.title }} <br> brand {{ item.brand }} <br> ${{ 
       item.regular_price.value }}
        <div class="btn me-md-2" id="btn" @click="$emit('addToCart', value)"> 
          Add to cart
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```